# Python doesn't differentiate len() of list and string?

Tags: python, list, pandas, string-length

For example I have this pandas simple data frame:

```
>> print(file)
       Name
    0  ['junior','senior']
    1  freshgrad
```

when I tried using :

```
>> len(file[0])
2
```

but for the second one

```
>> len(file[1])
9
```

But I want the second one to calculate as `1` how to differentiate between these two?

1. I have tried using `.join()` but it still calculate as `9`
2. I have tried `list.count` but I got an error

Comment: If you want to calculate the number of values, you need to make sure that single values are stored as length-1 lists.

Comment: freshgrad is a string and not an array. If you had `1 ['freshgrad']` you would get `len(file[1])=1`

Comment: @EliSadoff So, for the 'freshgrad' I need to change it from array to string?

Comment: No, `freshgrad` is currently a string, and you want it to be an array.

Comment: @EliSadoff oh yes! I was a bit confused. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

freshgrad is a string
so len(file[1]) means that you are calculate the length of this string.It is 9.
if file[1] is a list containing freshgrad like['freshgrad'],len(file[1]) will be 1.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do what you want is to check the data type of the item in question.  You can use:

```
if isinstance(item, list):
    ...
```

And:

```
if isinstance(item, str):
    ...
```

In the case of a string, you can then use 1 for the length if you wish.  Note that it's better to use `isinstance(item, dtype)` than `type(item) == dtype` because it will automatically work on subclassed types.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own length function, which uses the type to determine how to calculate the length:

```
def mylen(data):
    return len(data) if isinstance(data,list) else 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.size`:

```
In [301]: file = pd.Series([['junior','senior'], 'freshgrad'])

In [302]: file.apply(np.size)
Out[302]: 
0    2
1    1
dtype: int64

In [327]: np.size(file[0])
Out[327]: 2

In [328]: np.size(file[1])
Out[328]: 1
```

But to some extent this might just be delaying your agony.  When the objects in
a Series (or any kind sequence) have different types, the code tends require type-checking or `try..except`s to handle the various types differently. (In fact, this is what `np.size` is doing. Under the hood `np.size` is using `try..except` to handle the exceptional case.)

Life is usually simpler (and therefore better) when all the objects in a sequence have the same type. So it is preferable to build a Series whose elements are all lists:

```
In [301]: file = pd.Series([['junior','senior'], ['freshgrad']])
```